# Cosa vuol dire "chiedere conto" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Zinco* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Ronzando intorno a Rita mi accorsi di una seconda circostanza fortunata: dalla borsa della ragazza sporgeva una copertina ben nota, giallastra col bordo rosso, e sul frontispizio stava un corvo con un libro nel becco. Il titolo? Si leggeva soltanto «AGNA» e «TATA», ma tanto bastava: era il mio viatico di quei mesi, la storia senza tempo di Giovanni Castorp in magico esilio sulla Montagna Incantata. Ne **chiesi conto** a Rita, pieno d'ansia per il suo giudizio, quasi che il libro lo avessi scritto io: e mi dovetti presto convincere che lei, quel romanzo, lo stava leggendo in tutt'altro modo.

Quello che non riesco a capire in questo passaggio è cosa significa che il narratore, un giovane che stava cercando di avvicinarsi a questa ragazza (si era detto, per esempio, "era un pezzo che giravo intorno a Rita, preparavo mentalmente brillanti attacchi di discorso, e poi al momento decisivo non osavo enunciarli e rimandavo al giorno dopo"), "ne chiesi conto a Rita". Ho trovato l'espressione ["chiedere conto" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conto2) (punto 2.b), ma il significato riportato, cioè,

> domandar ragione a qualcuno del suo operato

non sembra avere molto senso nel contesto del testo. Potreste spiegarmi che vuol dire?

Comment: In realtà la definizione di Treccani è corretta. 

***Chiedere conto***




richiedere pressantemente una spiegazione, una giustificazione: *gli chiese conto del suo operato, mi chiese conto del mio comportamento, gli chiederò conto dei suoi errori.* 
https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/chiedere-conto

Comment: Sì, @Hachi: lungi da me pensare che una definizione del Treccani possa non essere corretta. Ma, allora, il significato sarebbe richiedere pressantemente a quella ragazza di giustificare che cosa? Magari perché aveva scelto di leggere quel libro?

Comment: E poi un tale atteggiamento da parte dell'io narrante non sarebbe in contraddizione con il fatto di voler avvicinarsi a una ragazza con cui non era mai riuscito a parlare?

Answer (score 1):

Significa chiedere pressantemente una spiegazione. Il mio capo `chiede conto` delle mie azioni. In italiano si usa anche `dare conto`, io do conto al mio capo.

Il sistema periodico, di Primo Levi l'ho letto alcuni anni fa. Molto bello come libro.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Quindi, il significato sarebbe che il narratore chiese insistentemente alla ragazza cosa gli sembrava il libro?

Comment: Ti ringrazio! In sostanza Primo chiede alla ragazza un parere riguardo del libro, in modo ansioso. Probabilmente lo usa come rafforzativo per far capire che non era un chiedere semplice. Bisognerebbe vedere l'intero contesto in cui si colloca questo capoverso.

Comment: Dopo il brano che ho riportato, semplicemente si spiega che le cose che interessavano a Rita e a Primo di quel libro erano diverse.